# FOr some reason will not compile

Tags: python

hello this is my first program ive tried making, someone please help me as i cant get this to compile. It always says invalid character in line 2. Pls help.

EDIT: [Here is a link to my code](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23menu%0Aprint+(%22+1.+Convert+inches+to+centimetres.%22)%0Aprint+(%222.+Convert+feet+to+meters.%22)%0Aprint+(%223.+Convert+miles+to+kilometers.%22)%0Aprint%0A+%0Amenu_selection+%3D+input('Enter+your+selection%3A+')%0A+%0Awhile+menu_selection+%3C+1+or+menu_selection+%3E+3%3A%0A++++print+(%22That+is+an+invalid+selection.%22)%0Amenu_selection+%3D+input('Enter+1,+2,+or+3%3A+')%0A+%0Aif+menu_selection+%3D%3D+1%3A%0A+%0A++++inches+%3D+input('Enter+the+number+of+inches%3A+')%0Acentimeters+%3D+inches+*+2.54%0Aprint+(%22That+is+equal+to',+centimeters,+'centimeters.%22)%0Aelif+menu_selection+%3D%3D+2%3A%0Afeet+%3D+input('Enter+the+number+of+feet%3A+')%0Ameters+%3D+feet+*+0.3048%0Aprint+(%22That+is+equal+to',+meters,+'meters.%22)%0Aelif+menu_selection+%3D%3D+3%3A%0Amiles+%3D+input('Enter+the+number+of+miles%3A+')%0Akilometers+%3D+miles+*+1.609%0Aprint+(%22That+is+equal+to',+kilometers,+'kilometers.%22)%0A&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

```
print (” 1. Convert inches to centimeters.”)
print (“2. Convert feet to meters.”)
print (“3. Convert miles to kilometers.”)
print

menu_selection = input('Enter your selection: ')

while menu_selection < 1 or menu_selection > 3:
print (“That is an invalid selection.”)
menu_selection = input('Enter 1, 2, or 3: ')

if menu_selection == 1:

inches = input('Enter the number of inches: ')
centimeters = inches * 2.54
print (“That is equal to', centimeters, 'centimeters.”)
elif menu_selection == 2:
feet = input('Enter the number of feet: ')
meters = feet * 0.3048
print (“That is equal to', meters, 'meters.”)
elif menu_selection == 3:
miles = input('Enter the number of miles: ')
kilometers = miles * 1.609
 (“That is equal to', kilometers, 'kilometers.”​)
```

Comment: your double quotes are not valid ASCII double-quote ! you need `"`

Comment: Do you really have `“` in your code? Replace them by straight quotes `"` or simply use everywhere single quotes `'`

Comment: thank you for your help. I added a link to code . I fixed the original problem, although it seems i am still getting errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation is off, and you're using the wrong character for delimiting strings, it must be a normal double-quote. In other words, change this:

```
print (” 1. Convert inches to centimeters.”)
```

Into this:

```
print (" 1. Convert inches to centimetres.")
```

This kind of errors happen when you copy-paste code from a digital book or similar electronic content that didn't use proper typesetting, and in Python you must absolutely respect indentation as it was intended in the original source - whitespace matters in Python programs.

Comment: I agree but there is also an indentation issue.

Comment: Ok, added that at the beginning. Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, you wrote exactly what I would have written.

Comment: thank you for your help. I added a link to code . I fixed the original problem, although it seems i am still getting errors

Comment: @user4517812 what errors? add all the information, including stack traces, etc.

Comment: i edited my original post to include my code in a compiler

Comment: @user4517812 fix the formatting, once again: whitespace matters in Python. You can't write lines at different indentation levels if they're supposed to be inside a control structure (say, an `if` or a `for`).

Comment: I have fixed it. thank you once again for your help. I appreciate it